# regular expression to select strings like "queue: 'shopify pull orders'"

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression to find a string that starts with queue: followed by white spaces, then a single quote , then a string of words with spaces, finally closed by a single quote

e.g.

queue: 'shopify pull orders'

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you using, the syntax sometimes is different?

Answer (score 0):

```
          queue:\s+\'(.*?)\'
```

This will give you the required string.

Answer (score 0):

If the string starts with "queue:" than the regular expression must be modified as follows:
^queue:\s*'(\w*\s*){0,}'

Here is my solution:

```
 String str = "queue: 'shopify pull orders'"; 
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^queue:\\s*'(\\w*\\s*){0,}'");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
   while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
   }
```